# NLTK fdist.plot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, nltk

I'm not having any luck generating a plot of my frequency distribution using fdist.plot() in NLTK.

```
bgr = nltk.bigrams(words_filtered)
fdist2 = nltk.FreqDist(bgr)
plot2 = fdist2.plot()
plot2.show() # cause Python to be unresponsive
plot2.savefig("plot2.jpg") # cause Python to be unresponsive
```

I have ensured that Matplotlib is installed so that isn't the issue. Running these commands through terminal.

When run in terminal everything up to that point prints fine and then the python application starts bouncing in the doc (MacOS) and it hangs.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it on a Jupyter notebool:

```
from nltk import bigrams, FreqDist
from nlkt.corpus import brown

fd = FreqDist(brown.words())
fd.plot(30)
```

You should see something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using NLTK 3 with Anaconda 4.6.14 and I found that you need:

```
fdist.plot(30).draw()
```